# Connecting Producer and Pipe to extract the result

Tags: haskell, pipe, haskell-pipes

Having a producer of type `Producer ByteString IO ()` and a pipe of type `Pipe ByteString a IO ()` how do I compose an effect, which will result in `IO a` when run?

Here's my best attempt:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
import Pipes
import Data.ByteString

run :: forall a. IO a
run = runEffect $ 
  (undefined :: Producer ByteString IO ()) >-> (undefined :: Pipe ByteString a IO ())
```

It fails with the following:

```
Couldn't match type `Void' with `()'
Expected type: IO a
  Actual type: IO ()
In the expression:
  runEffect
  $ (undefined :: Producer ByteString IO ())
    >-> (undefined :: Pipe ByteString a IO ())
In an equation for `run':
    run
      = runEffect
        $ (undefined :: Producer ByteString IO ())
          >-> (undefined :: Pipe ByteString a IO ())
```

Comment: Is that the full source and error message? It looks very strange! After all, it says it's trying to unify `Void` and `()` but `Void` doesn't appear in the expected type.

Comment: @DanielWagner `Void` appears [in the signature of `Effect` type alias](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/pipes-4.0.0/docs/Pipes-Core.html#t:Effect). Concerning the code and error - see updates.

Comment: Regardless of the solution to your problem, I'd complain to GHC HQ about how bad that error is!

Comment: Do you want the first value emitted?

Comment: I filed a [feature request on GHC Trac](http://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/8450) to improve this error message.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally, you need to compose a `Producer` with a `Consumer` in order to get an `Effect` which can be run by `runEffect`. That's not what you've got here, but fortunately, there are more ways to eliminate a `Proxy` than just `runEffect`.

Taking stock of what we have, this composition ends up with a `Producer`.

```
pipe :: Producer a IO ()
pipe = (undefined :: Producer ByteString IO ()) >-> (undefined :: Pipe ByteString a IO ())
```

The `Pipes.Prelude` module contains many other ways to eliminate `Producers` like `Pipes.Prelude.last`

```
last :: Monad m => Producer a m () -> m (Maybe a)
```

Probably the most general way to get `a`s out is to use `Pipes.Prelude.fold`

```
fold :: Monad m => (x -> a -> x) -> x -> (x -> b) -> Producer a m () -> m b
```

which is like `runEffect` except it reduces `Producers` to their underlying `Monad`. Since that's what we have it'll work great. Here's how we can implement `Pipes.Prelude.head`

```
slowHead = fold (\res a -> res <> First (Just a)) mempty getFirst
```

Though it's worth noting that `slowHead` consumes the entire `Producer` (and thus performs all of the needed effects) while `Pipes.Prelude.head` performs just the first one. It's much lazier!

Comment: You can also use `head` to get the first value.  It will be lazy and only run the producer long enough to get the first element.

Comment: Great! Thanks guys! So, the final result is `run = Pipes.head $ (undefined :: Producer ByteString IO ()) >-> (undefined :: Pipe ByteString a IO ())` with a type signature `run :: forall a. IO (Maybe a)`

Comment: @GabrielGonzalez Would the solution using `head` have the same effect as `run = runEffect $ ((undefined :: Producer ByteString IO ()) >> return Nothing) >-> ((undefined :: Pipe ByteString a IO ()) >> return Nothing) >-> (await >>= return . Just)`?

Comment: Oomph, yes. I'll change that answer to clarify that the `fold` solution I wrote has potentially massively different performance characteristics...

Comment: @NikitaVolkov Yes.  `head` is just more efficient.